# Iterate over NSArray filled with dates and comparing to another NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, for-loop, nsdate

I have an NSArray filled with about 30 dates in the NSDate format,

What I need to do is create another array from this, which contains a boolean for all of the dates from the first date to the last date.

ex Array 1
1/1/11
3/1/11
5/1/11

Array 2
Yes
No
Yes
No
Yes

I need this for tapku library calendar

This is what I have so far but the i never changes

```
int i=0;
for (NSDate *date = [[startingDate copy] autorelease]; [date compare: endingDate] < 0;
     date = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:24 * 60 * 60] ) {
    NSLog( @"%@ in [%@,%@]", date, startingDate, endingDate );

    int day1 = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] ordinalityOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit inUnit:NSEraCalendarUnit forDate:[eventDates objectAtIndex:i]];
    int day2 = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] ordinalityOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit inUnit:NSEraCalendarUnit forDate:date];

    if(day1-day2==0) {
        NSLog(@"yeh");
        i=i+1;
        //add yes to array2

    } else {
        NSLog(@"nah");
        NSLog(@"%i",i);
        //add no to array 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I quite understand what you want to do, but I'll give it a try.

Suppose you have 2 `NSDate`'s, call them `date1` and `date2`, and you want to mark any entries in an array of `NSDate`'s, call it `arrayOfDates`, that are between the 2 `NSDate`'s, or not, and store the `YES` or `NO` values in another array, call it `boolValuesOfDates`. Then try this method:

```
- (void)compareDatesOfArrayFromDate:(NSDate *)date1 toDate:(NSDate *)date2; {

  NSDate * firstDate;
  NSDate * secondDate;

  if([date1 timeIntervalSinceDate:date2] >= 0){
    firstDate = date2;
    secondDate = date1;
  }
  else{
    firstDate = date1;
    secondDate = date2;
  }

  if(boolValuesOfDates != nil)
    [boolValuesOfDates release]; // Release the YES/NO array for the new values.

  boolValuesOfDates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[arrayOfDates count]];

  BOOL isInbetweenDates;
  NSDate * curDate;

  for(int i = 0; i < [arrayOfDates count]; i++){
    curDate = [arrayOfDates objectAtIndex:i];
    isInbetweenDates = NO;
    if([curDate timeIntervalSinceDate:firstDate] >= 0){
      if([curDate timeIntervalSinceDate:secondDate] <= 0){
        isInbetweenDates = YES;
      }
    }
    [boolValuesOfDates addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:isInbetweenDates]];
  }
}
```

This method checks the order of the 2 entered `NSDate`'s, and then compares the `NSDate`'s in the array, and if they are in between, marks them with a `YES`, or `NO` otherwise. Hope that Helps!

Comment: This is pretty much what I wanted so THANKS, but seems to give me an out of bounds exception

Comment: If you post the actual error, it would be easier to help you. Also, Don't forget to accept the answer so that others know it was a help for later.

Comment: I gave up on this method and decided to try a different approach, but now that's giving another problem! [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222488/why-does-the-array-only-contain-the-final-mark)